# Заполнение массива случайными числами из диапазона [-15,15] с помощью Math.random

Tags: java, массивы

Не получается вывести массив из 12 случайных чисел из промежутка `[-15,15]`:

```
int[] array;
array = new int[12];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = ((int)(Math.random() * 12) - 15);
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

выводит только отрицательные числа

Comment: Задал вопрос ибо выводит только отрицательные числа

Comment: int[] array;
        array = new int[12];
        for (int i = 0; i <array.length ; i++) {
            array[i]=( (int)(Math.random()*12) - 15 );
            System.out.println(array[i]);

Comment: Чем плох [`Random.nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))?

Comment: @soon тут непонятно автору нужны целы иди дробные числа.

Comment: @anber, Судя по тому, что он все это дело приводит к инту - целые.

Comment: @soon да, тогда nextInt() вполне подойдет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()).

`Math.random()` возвращает число типа `double` от 0 до 1.

Вы зачем-то множите это значение на 12.

По сути, у вас интервал от -15 до 15 включительно, плюс 0, т.е. диапазон 31. Согласны?

Вот 31 и надо множить на `Math.random()` - будете получать числа от 0 до 30.

Чтобы получить не от 0 до 30, а от -15 до 15, нужно отнять 15, что вы совершенно верно сделали.

**UPD**. Обновил ответ, спасибо за исправление.
Первоначально была такая мысль:

```
int[] array = new int[12];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 30) - 15);
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Но немного подумал и понял, что значения будут не совсем корректные, да и ответ @Regent попроще.

Comment: не 30, а 31, не вводите в заблуждение)

Comment: `Math.random()` возвращает число типа double из промежутка [0, 1), где 0 включается, а 1 - нет. Поэтому, в данном случае, при умножении на 30 вы никогда не получите число 15.

Comment: @STepeR да, спасибо, действительно забыл :)

Answer (score 7):

Проблема в том, что `(int)(Math.random() * 12)` генерирует числа от `0` до `11`, а нужно генерировать от `0` до `30`:

```
int[] array = new int[12];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = ((int)(Math.random() * 31) - 15);
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://goo.gl/QFThlX).

Answer (score 3):

Использование `Math.random()` обязательно? Зачем генерировать дроби если всё равно нужны целые числа?
Ведь гораздо проще использовать `nextInt(int bound)` класса `java.util.Random`.

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

[(Из документации)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))

Итак, этот метод генерирует случайные целые числа из диапазона `[0, bound)`. Нам нужен диапазон `[-15, 15]`, т.е. `[-15, 16)`. Для получения чисел из такого диапазона нужно:

1. Сгенерировать числа из положительного диапазона, по длине равному
   диапазону из условия. Т.е. получаем диапазон `[0, 16+15) = [0, 31)`
2. Вычесть из каждого полученного числа `15`, т.е. сдвинуть диапазон на
   `15` вправо.

В итоге, строка `array[i] = ((int)(Math.random() * 12) - 15);` заменяется на `array[i] = random.nextInt(31) - 15;`. Объект `random` нужно создать где-нибудь перед выполнением цикла.

**Теперь замечания по коду.**

1. Зачем разбивать объявление и присвоение? 2 первые строки лучше
   объединить: `int[] array = new int[12];`
2. В вопросе написано, что массив нужно просто вывести. Нужно ли его
   хранить? Если нет, то лучше генерировать числа и тут же их выводить:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        System.out.println(random.nextInt(31) - 15);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Random rand = new Random();

public static int getRandom(int lo, int hi) {
   return lo + rand.nextInt(hi - lo + 1);
} // getRandom
```

Comment: Добавьте текст к вашему коду.

Answer (score -1):

Можно и так:

```
array[i] = ((int)(Math.random()*16) - (int)(Math.random()*16));
```